# Convert time_t to tm in a particular timezome

Tags: c, time

The [`localtime_r`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime) function converts a `time_t` timestamp to a `struct tm` in the *current* timezone.

How can you convert a UTC `time_t` to a `struct tm` in a different timezone, e.g. to the time in, say, Sydney Australia, taking into account daylight savings and whatever else, and without affecting uses of `localtime` in other parts of the program?

Comment: Is this question about thread safety of time conversion?

Comment: This seems to do what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173578/converting-between-timezones-in-c

Comment: I don't think standard C functions help you here. As far as I know library functions simply give you current time and OS handles the timezones and daylight savings. So you'll probably need to use OS specific functions or external libraries.

Comment: Would it work to use `setenv` to change the value of `TZ`, call `localtime`, and then set `TZ` back to its previous value?

Comment: @NateEldredge that wouldn't be thread-safe?

Comment: You (originally) said *subsequent* uses.  If *concurrent* uses are an issue, I guess you could put a mutex around it, or fork a subprocess to handle the conversion.  I agree it's not a great solution.

Comment: @NateEldredge apologies.  Sadly I can't put a lock around localtime as it may be called by code in libraries I don't directly control in other threads.  And the idea of forking is grotesque!  I'm kinda frustrated I can't find a sensible API for time zone handling in C :(

Answer (score 0):

NetBSD's C runtime library includes some functions to deal with arbitrary timezones (see [NetBSD 6.1.5 - man page for ctime (netbsd section 3)](http://www.unix.com/man-page/netbsd/3/CTIME/). To get similar functions in other projects, you can use code from IANA's [Time Zone Database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones), particularly, its `localtime.c`, `private.h` and `tzfile.h` files.